# Perl: Parse Excel with Search and Replace

Tags: regex, excel, perl, parsing

I'm building a PERL script to search and replace the EXCEL cell A1.  There is an error in my code, it will find "Apples" in the input file but will NOT write replace "Apples" with "Peaches" in the output file.

I have an XLS EXCEL INPUT file (file_in.xls) with the contents displayed below:

```
A---------------B
-----------------------
1 Apples  | Carrots
-----------------------
2 Oranges | Spinach
-----------------------
3 Grapes  | Celery 
-----------------------
```

I need to perform search/replace for Apples to Peaches in the cell (A1) for the EXCEL output file (file_out.xls):

```
A----------------B
-----------------------
1 Peaches | Carrots
-----------------------
2 Oranges | Spinach
-----------------------
3 Grapes  | Celery 
-----------------------
```

Here is the Perl code:

```
 use v5.10.0;
 use warnings;

 use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
 use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
 use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

 my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
 my $file1 = $parser->Parse("C:/Perl/scripts/file_in.xls");
 my $workbook_R = $parser->parse('file_in.xls');

 my $workbook_W = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('C:\Perl\scripts\file_out.xls');
 my $worksheet_W = $workbook_W->add_worksheet();

 my $sheet = ${ $file1->{Worksheet_R} }[0];

 for my $worksheet_R ( $workbook_R->worksheets() ) {

 my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_R->row_range();
 my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_R->col_range();

for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

        my $cell = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );
        next unless $cell;

        if($cell->value() =~ /Apples/) {
        $worksheet_R->write($cell,"Oranges");}
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: And what isn't working with your code? Where is the explicit question?

Comment: If it functions as it should, your script appears to be replacing 'Apples' with 'Oranges'.

Comment: When I open up the output file, no peaches is written to it.

Comment: You are not writing to the output file that you've opened -- look: `$worksheet_R->write($cell,"Oranges");`

Comment: I need the output excel file to replace "Apples" with "Peaches."

Comment: I tried to replace     worksheet_R->write$worksheet_R->write($cell,"Oranges"); with     worksheet_W->write$worksheet_R->write($cell,"Oranges"); and received an interpreter error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. You're not writing to the output file, `$worksheet_W`
2. You're not writing out the contents of the cells that don't have `Apples` in them.

   ```
   for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
     for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

       my $cell = $worksheet_R->get_cell( $row, $col );
       // if the cell contains Apples, write 'Peaches' instead
       if($cell->value() =~ /Apples/) {
         $worksheet_W->write($row, $col,"Peaches");
       }
       else {
         // print the existing cell contents
         $worksheet_W->write($row, $col, $cell);
       }
     }
   }
   ```